# Ant: How to include only certain transitive dependencies from the artifact?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

Just as an example, suppose I only need hamcrest in junit:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.7">
    <include name="hamcrest*"/>
</dependency>
```

However it seems ant still pulls everything in junit. Maybe I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

Hamcrest is not longer a junit dependency. Take a look at the POM file for the module, the dependencies section is empty:

- [junit 4.7](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit%7C4.7%7Cjar)

Reportedly it has been incorporated into the junit jar (See [MAVENUPLOAD-1651](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAVENUPLOAD-1651))

This explains why the following dependency will only retrieve a single jar:

```
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.7"/>
```